# Unique value finder

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, array, memory-optimization

For our first assignment in our algorithm class we are suppose to solve several different questions using information from a 2D array. We are also suppose to optimize our code to get more marks on our assignment. We also are only allowed to use 1D and 2D arrays as the only data structure.

The problem was find the unique values in a 2D array (`int data[][]`) of 1000x250 values. The range of that is from 2000000 to 2200000. My idea was to make a 1D array (with 200000 indexes) and look at the number in the 2D array and see it matches anything prior to it in the 1D array, and if not, add it. However, with all the other questions, it takes a few seconds before it will actually finish.

```
int[] uniqueValues = new int[200000];
    boolean isUnique = true;
    int uniqueCounter = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

            for (int x = 0; x < uniqueCounter; x++) {

                if (data[i][j] != uniqueValues[x]) {
                    isUnique = true;
                } else {
                    isUnique = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (isUnique) {
                uniqueValues[uniqueCounter] = data[i][j];
                uniqueCounter++;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

## Linear time solution

Given that your values are restricted to the range `[2000000..2200000]`, you can do the following:

1. Iterate through your matrix and keep a count of each of the numbers that you find in the matrix.  You will need an array of size 200001 to keep these counts.
2. Iterate through your count array.  Whatever numbers have a count of 1 are unique.

Here is some sample code:

```
    final int MIN_RANGE = 2000000;
    final int MAX_RANGE = 2200000;
    int[] count = new int[MAX_RANGE-MIN_RANGE+1];

    // Determine the count for each number.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            count[data[i][j] - MIN_RANGE]++;
        }
    }

    // Find out how many unique numbers there are.
    int uniqueCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RANGE-MIN_RANGE+1; i++) {
        if (count[i] == 1) {
            uniqueCount++;
        }
    }

    // Create an array of all the unique numbers.
    int [] uniqueValues = new int[uniqueCount];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < MAX_RANGE-MIN_RANGE+1; i++) {
        if (count[i] == 1) {
            uniqueValues[j++] = i + MIN_RANGE;
        }
    }
```

This will reduce the worst case time from \$O(n^2)\$ to \$O(n)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of elements in the matrix (this depends on the range of values being smaller than the size of the matrix as in the question).  If the range of values was not restricted, you could still do better by sorting the array of values and then scanning the sorted array for unique elements.  That would take \$O(n \log n)\$ time.  If you could use data structures other than arrays, you could use a `HashMap` instead of a `count` array and get \$O(n)\$ time again.

Comment: For memory optimization purposes the count array could be a byte array. There's no need to count occurrences beyond 2. Limiting the counting would lead to a slightly worse time performance. On the other hand, the second loop could be omitted altogether by inspecting the count before incrementing.

Answer (score 6):

Your algorithm goes through each cell, and for each cell, you compare the values against each possible value (200,000 of them). If you call the cells the input size (\$n\$) and the distinct values (\$m\$), then your complexity is \$O(nm)\$.

You cannot avoid the scan of each cell in the matrix (the n part is required, but you can reduce the effort for computing unique values.

If you have a single array for storing unique values, you can store it in an ordered format. A binary search in that array would require just a \$log(m)\$ time requirement. If the value is not in the seen-so-far values, then add it.

The code would be something like:

```
int[] uniqueValues = new int[500];
int uniqueCounter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

        int value = data[i][j];
        int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(uniqueValues, 0, uniqueCounter, value);

        if (pos >= 0) {
            // seen already, just continue;
            continue;
        }

        int ip = -pos - 1;

        if (uniqueValues.length == uniqueCounter) {
            // expand the array if needed.
            uniqueValues = Arrays.copyOf(uniqueValues, uniqueCounter * 2);
        }

        // insert the new value in order in to the seen-so-far values.
        System.arrayCopy(uniqueValues, ip, uniqueValues, ip+1, uniqueCounter - ip);
        uniqueValues[ip] = value;

    }
}
```

Now your algorithm becomes \$O(n \log m)\$ if there are lots of common values, or, at worst case, \$O(nm)\$... which is what you have, if each value is unique.

The unique values in the input matrix will be the first `uniqueCount` values in `uniqueValues`

Of course, a better solution would probably be a set, but since you can only use arrays.....